# RealityKit – Loading Reality Composer scenes with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm trying to load different models on face using SwiftUI, RealityKit and ARKit.

```
struct AugmentedRealityView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var modelName: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
        let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()

        arView.session.run(configuration, options: [.removeExistingAnchors, 
                                                    .resetTracking])
    
        loadModel(name: modelName, arView: arView)
    
        return arView
    
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }

    private func loadModel(name: String, arView: ARView) {

        var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
        cancellable = ModelEntity.loadAsync(named: name).sink(
                 receiveCompletion: { loadCompletion in
            
            if case let .failure(error) = loadCompletion {
                print("Unable to load model: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }                
            cancellable?.cancel()
        },
        receiveValue: { model in
            
            let faceAnchor = AnchorEntity(.face)
            arView.scene.addAnchor(faceAnchor)
            
            faceAnchor.addChild(model)
            
            model.scale = [1, 1, 1]
        })
    }
}
```

This is how I load them but when the camera view opens and loads one model then the other models won't be loaded. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Read this post to find out how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618102/multi-face-detection-in-realitykit/59809624#59809624

Answer (score 0):

When the value of your `Binding` changes, SwiftUI is calling your `updateUIView(_:,context:)` implementation, which does noting.

Additionally, you are not storing the `AnyCancellable`. When the token returned by `sink` gets deallocated the request will be cancelled. That could result in unexpected failures when trying to load lager models.

To fix both of these issue, use a `Coordinator`.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import ARKit

struct AugmentedRealityView: UIViewRepresentable {
    class Coordinator {
        private var token: AnyCancellable?
        private var currentModelName: String?
        
        fileprivate func loadModel(_ name: String, into arView: ARView) {
            // Only load model if the name is different from the previous one
            guard name != currentModelName else {
                return
            }
            currentModelName = name
            
            // This is optional
            // When the token gets overwritten
            // the request gets cancelled
            // automatically
            token?.cancel()
            
            token = ModelEntity.loadAsync(named: name).sink(
                receiveCompletion: { loadCompletion in
                    
                    if case let .failure(error) = loadCompletion {
                        print("Unable to load model: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                },
                receiveValue: { model in
                    
                    let faceAnchor = AnchorEntity(.camera)
                    arView.scene.addAnchor(faceAnchor)
                    
                    faceAnchor.addChild(model)
                    
                    model.scale = [1, 1, 1]
                })
            }
        
        fileprivate func cancelRequest() {
            token?.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    @Binding var modelName: String
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    static func dismantleUIView(_ uiView: ARView, coordinator: Coordinator) {
        coordinator.cancelRequest()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        
        arView.session.run(configuration, options: [.removeExistingAnchors,
                                                    .resetTracking])
        
        context.coordinator.loadModel(modelName, into: arView)
        
        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.loadModel(modelName, into: uiView)
    }
}
```

We create a nested `Coordinator` class that holds the `AnyCancellable` token and move the `loadModel` function into the `Coordinator`.
Other than a SwiftUI `View`, the `Coordinator` is a `class` that lives while your view is visible (always a remember that SwiftUI might create and destroy your `View` at will, its lifecycle is not related to the actual "view" that is shown on screen).

In out `loadModel` class we double check that the value of our `Binding` actually changed so that we don't cancel an ongoing request for the same model when SwiftUI updates our `View`, e.g. because of a change in the environment.

Then we implement the `makeCoordinator` function to construct one of our `Coordinator` objects.
Both in `makeUIView` and in `updateUIView` we call the `loadModel` function on our `Coordinator`.

The `dimantleUIView` method is optional. When the `Coordinator` gets deconstructed our `token` gets released as well, which will trigger Combine into canceling ongoing requests.